# ng2-material TypeError: all_2.Media.hasMedia is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use **[ng2-material](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material)** with angular2.

While trying *Sidenav* component, I am getting these errors:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: all_2.Media.hasMedia is not a function in [hasMedia('gt-sm') ? 'side' : 'over' in AppComponent@17:32]
>
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: TypeError: all_2.Media.hasMedia is not a function in [hasMedia('gt-sm') ? 'side' : 'over' in AppComponent@17:32]
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: all_2.Media.hasMedia is not a function
>   ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   TypeError: all_2.Media.hasMedia is not a function
>       at AppComponent.hasMedia (http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:67:40)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_AppComponent_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_AppComponent:114:31)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9609:14)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9592:12)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9671:14)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9596:12)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9581:12)
>       at ChangeDetectorRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:5252:16)
>       at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12954:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>   ERROR CONTEXT:
>   [object Object]

And there are many more errors all related to `all_2.Media.hasMedia`

Probably this is the code that might be causing it

```
hasMedia(breakSize: string): boolean {
    return Media.hasMedia(breakSize);
}
```

I have followed the [instructions on ng2-material site](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/) and already got ng2-material working.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The code sample that was originally posted on ng2-material has been updated with a fixed version. This also tripped me up as well and I was seeing the same error that Shri has posted. The fix is to inject Media into the class and use the class local version:

```
constructor(public sidenav: SidenavService,
            public media: Media) {
}

hasMedia(breakSize: string): boolean {
    return this.media.hasMedia(breakSize);
}
```

as explained now on the ng2-material website:

https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/components/sidenav

Comment: are you referring to this thread to get this answer? https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/issues/167

Comment: No, I just revisted ng2-material's documentation

Answer (score -1):

You are using the example code as it is. As you can see, it calls a "hasMedia()" method somewhere. This needs to get defined in your component. all_2 something like this points only to your context.

Comment: I have hasMedia() defined in my component and is being called since I used console.log in the method and checked. Now my function also calls a hadMedia() from Media component in the library. Just check the demo site I've mentioned in the first line of my question.